# Update Variable in Abstract Class at Initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, abstract-class

So at begining I like to set up some variables, which will later used. I am building some graph moving parts, where I must set up Step for every movement (if X change for 1 then Value change 1*Step ... bla bla).

I have MainWindowViewModel (short version):

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
       // Initialization
       Step = 3;
    }
}
```

DiagramObject Class:

```
public abstract class DiagramObject : ViewModelBase
{
        public abstract double X { get; set; }
        public abstract string Xmeaning { get; set; }

        public abstract double Y { get; set; }
        public abstract string Ymeaning { get; set; }
}
```

So there inside I have defined "Steps":

```
public class DiagramNode : DiagramObject
{
        public int xstep = 3;
        public int ystep = 1;
        public int xstepvalue = 5;
        public int ystepvalue = 5;

        private double _x;
        public override double X
        {
            get { return _x; }
            set
            {
                //"Grid Snapping"

                _x = (Math.Round(value / xstep)) * xstep;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("X");

                double minutes = (_x / xstep) * xstepvalue;
                TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
                _xmeaning = interval.ToString();

                NotifyPropertyChanged("Xmeaning");
            }
        }

        private string _xmeaning;
        public override string Xmeaning
        {
            get { return _xmeaning; }
            set
            {
                //"Grid Snapping"

                _xmeaning = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Xmeaning");
            }
        }

        private double _y;
        public override double Y
        {
            get { return _y; }
            set
            {
                //"Grid Snapping"

                _y = (Math.Round(value / ystep)) * ystep;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Y");

                double keks = (_y / ystep) * ystepvalue;
                _ymeaning = keks.ToString();

                NotifyPropertyChanged("Ymeaning");
            }
        }

        private string _ymeaning;
        public override string Ymeaning
        {
            get { return _ymeaning; }
            set
            {
                //"Grid Snapping"

                _ymeaning = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Ymeaning");
            }
        }
}
```

My question is How to update "xstep", "ystep" and others steps inside DiagramNode class from MainWindowViewModel at beginning of the program?

So when I start the program step will be defined and updated into DiagramNode class - now I have defined direct in class.

I hope that I give enough code for understanding the concept (if not say so). If any question please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your MainWindowViewModel will need to have an instance of the DiagramNode class instantiated so that it can access the properties to modify them.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    DiagramNode myDiagramNode = new DiagramNode();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        // Initialization
        Step = 3;
        myDiagramNode.xstep = 3;
    }
}
```

Typically, though, it is a better practice to have variables like xstep and ystep to be set as private, and have accessors which can handle the setting/getting of the values, like so

```
public class DiagramNode : DiagramObject
{
    private int xstep;

    public int XStep
    {
        get { return this.xstep; }
        set { this.xstep = value; }
    }

    ...
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    DiagramNode myDiagramNode = new DiagramNode();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        myDiagramNode.XStep = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set them via a constructor overload

`public class DiagramNode(int xstep, int ystep)
{
     // set your values
}`